# Jupyter/Colab won't load/update local files properly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

When importing local files, if I add/change functions then it doesn't update.

Local File
Named Dataset3:

```
def function_thingy(abc, bcd):
    return None

def added_more_functions(blah):
    return None
```

In Colab:

```
import Dataset3

Dataset3??
```

Output:

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'Dataset3' from '/storage/homes/tejaspan/FlowVO/Dataset3.py'>
File:        /storage/homes/tejaspan/FlowVO/Dataset3.py
Source:     
def function_thingy(abc, bcd):
    return None

def added_more_functions(blah):
    return None
```

In Colab:

```
import Dataset3

#Dataset3??
Dataset3.function_thingy??
```

Output:

```
Object `Dataset3.function_thingy` not found.
```

In Colab:

```
import Dataset3

#Dataset3??
#Dataset3.function_thingy??
Dataset3.added_more_functions??
```

Output:

```
Object `Dataset3.added_more_functions` not found.
```

I don't have a good idea if somethings wrong or if it's the expected result. Restarting the kernels fixes the issue.